# ng-class not working with object and string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am new to angular js . I have used ng-class.here,

```
ng-class="[{'highlighter-row-Class' : (file.id == 1 && file.processed),
    'bold-row-Class' : lastSelectedResumeId == file.attributes.name, 
    'failed-doc': !file.processed }, getClassForHrms(file)]"
```

**css**

```
.missingfieldspresent {
  color: red;
}
.documentduplicate {
  color: purple;
}
.documentuploadfailed {
  color: deeppink;
}
```

**Function**

```
$scope.getClassForHrms = function (file) {
    if (file.attributes.hrmsMandatoryFieldsMissing) {
        return "missingfieldspresent";
    } else if (file.attributes.isDocumentDuplicated) {
        return "documentduplicate";
    } else if (!file.attributes.isDocumentDuplicated) {
        return "documentuploadfailed";
    }
};
```

**Rendered Html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles" ng-class="[{'highlighter-row-Class' : (file.id == 1 &amp;&amp; file.processed), 
    'bold-row-Class' : lastSelectedResumeId == file.attributes.name, 
    'failed-doc': !file.processed }, getClassForHrms(file)]" 
    class="ng-scope [object Object] documentduplicate">
```

Now, Here what is happening it is taking the object so, that class is not getting added. Is there any way to use that class .

How can I do this ?

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

Answer (score -1):

I think the syntax is slightly wrong for the ng-class (lose the square brackets).

`ng-class="{'highlighter-row-Class' : (file.id == 1 && file.processed),
    'bold-row-Class' : lastSelectedResumeId == file.attributes.name, 
    'failed-doc': !file.processed }, getClassForHrms(file)"`